# OpenCV ERROR - <unknown> is not a numpy array

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I get this error:

```
<unknown> is not a numpy array
```

when executing this code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

try:

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while (cap.isOpened()):
        ret,img=cap.read()
        cv2.imshow('output',img)
        img2=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
        cv2.imshow('gray_scale',img2)
        imgthreshold=cv2.inRange(img,cv2.cv.Scalar(3,3,125),cv2.cv.Scalar(40,40,255),)
        cv2.imshow('thresholded',imgthreshold)

        k=cv2.waitKey(10)
        if k==27:
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


except Exception as inst:

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    print("Eroor!!")
    print(inst)
    raise
```

Here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\... ...\camara.py", line 14, in <module>
        imgthreshold=cv2.inRange(img,cv2.cv.Scalar(3,3,125),cv2.cv.Scalar(40,40,255),)
TypeError: <unknown> is not a numpy array
```

I hope you can help me to solve this. I already check all the dependencies and they work fine also if I delete the line

```
imgthreshold=cv2.inRange(img,cv2.cv.Scalar(3,3,125),cv2.cv.Scalar(40,40,255),)
```

and the next one, the program work without problems

Comment: You have a comma at the end of your `cv2.inRange(...)` function call, turning the three arguments into a single tuple. Try removing that trailing comma.

Comment: @Evert, adding a trailing comma in a function call will not cause the arguments to be packed into a single tuple.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didn't work, the problem remains the same

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace?

Comment: @jojonas here it is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\... ...\camara.py", line 14, in <module>
    imgthreshold=cv2.inRange(img,cv2.cv.Scalar(3,3,125),cv2.cv.Scalar(40,40,255),)
TypeError: <unknown> is not a numpy array

Comment: Does it do what you want if you replace `cv2.cv.Scalar(3,3,125)` with just `[3,3,125]`?

Comment: @askewchan, no, but I just post the solution, you have to define some parts of the function like numpy arrays

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the status returned by the [VideoCapture::read](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-read) function. It returns a boolean flag indicating whether the returned image is valid at all.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

try:

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while (cap.isOpened()):
        ret,img=cap.read()
        if not ret:
            continue

        cv2.imshow('output',img)
        img2=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
        cv2.imshow('gray_scale',img2)
        imgthreshold=cv2.inRange(img,cv2.cv.Scalar(3,3,125),cv2.cv.Scalar(40,40,255),)
        cv2.imshow('thresholded',imgthreshold)

        k=cv2.waitKey(10)
        if k==27:
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


except Exception as inst:

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    print("Eroor!!")
    print(inst)
    raise
```

Comment: The VideoCapture function is working without any problem, as I say if, you delete the trouble line, the program show tow displays with the correct image capture

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution, it is to convert the top parameters of colors to find into a numpy array -->

```
imgthreshold=cv2.inRange(img,np.array(cv2.cv.Scalar(3,3,125)),np.array(cv2.cv.Scalar(40,40,255)),)
```